# ms access - use function in criteria section

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I would like to use a function in the criteria section of my access table. Is this possible? I want to make the criteria area dynamic, so I thought if I add a function from a module it could work.

Comment: Can you post your query and your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use a user function (or any other VBA function) in the criteria of your queries. Just be mindful of the fact that it will pull the data down locally to do the filtering work so if that is your only filter criteria and you are querying a large table over a network you might run into problems